# Get access_token from restapi with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I have a restapi with bearer authentication. From Postman I can get the access_token without any problem, but when I try to get the token from another c# application always throw a AggregateException.

Correct
[image]
Error
[image]

Anyone have any idea of what the problem could be?

-----------------EDIT---------------------

Trying to control the exception I found this error:
[image]

I don't know how to traslate properly but it says something like:

"it's not possible to establish a connection, the destination machine denied connection 127.0.0.1:2541"

Any ideas?

-----------------SOLUTION---------------------

Sorry for your time, but as Equalsk pointed in comments, the problem was in the caller method that pass a wrong port number in the parameters url.

Comment: Don't use `.Result`, make your method `async` and use `await client.SendAsync(...)`

Comment: I tried, also with client.PostAsync... same result.

Comment: Then go and look into how to flatten aggregate exceptions read what the exception says is wrong.

Comment: i updated question, any idea now?

Comment: Well your successful Postman request shows the address `http://localhost:25419/token` while your exception shows the address `http://127.0.0.1/2541` which has the `9` missing off the end...

Comment: Thank you, I dind't realise that the problem was in the caller method...

Answer (score 0):

`Authentication Provider` and `Authentication Validator` must be in the same machine key:
so try to add a `machinekey` element in the same way in both of your `web.config`.

[machineKey Element MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
<machineKey validationKey="2C3639E274F1227EFFEFA8D605E9AC5282A771945CB03FE61BD40D887C5D77CB27BF646E8C875945614943FD008CA593BA80F85AA2BF0DDF4CA342F235" decryptionKey="30C268F15CC28500B32A832E45555834399EB1CC534AC6D34EB2782362558426" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

*Hope it would be helpful.*